# Django - Block tags in included templates get overridden by calling template

Tags: django, include, block, extends, overriding

I have a template that includes another template.  This included template has block tags in it.

Example:

base.html

```
BASE
{% block title %}Base Title{% endblock %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

template1.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Extended Title{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
   Extended content
   {% include 'include.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

include.html

```
{% block title %}Include Title{% endblock %}
{% block another_content %}Include Content{% endblock %}
```

What I'm expecting is if I render template.html I should get, which I do under 1.1.1

```
BASE
Extended Title
Extended content
Include Title
Include Content
```

But I actually get this when I switched to 1.2.1 and 1.2.3:

```
BASE
Extended Title
Extended Content
Extended Title
Include Content
```

As you can see, the title block in include.html gets replaced with template1.html's title block.  This replacement only happens if the block names are the same, so if I change the title block in include.html, this doesnt occur.  It seems to me that it's including and extending at the same time?  Anyone know if this is expected/I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If you're **not using** `extends` in `include.html` then this behaviour is normal - I suppose that there was a bug in 1.1.1.

Excerpt from official documentation:

> Finally, note that you can't define multiple {% block %} tags with the same name in the same template. This limitation exists because a block tag works in "both" directions. That is, a block tag doesn't just provide a hole to fill -- it also defines the content that fills the hole in the parent. If there were two similarly-named {% block %} tags in a template, that template's parent wouldn't know which one of the blocks' content to use.

Read whole thing here: [Template Inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)

Answer (score -1):

If that's what you want, then the include.html should not contain any blocks at all, ie just:

```
Include Title
Include Content
```

Comment: It's kinda what I've said above :)