# Django - block tags in included templates don't work - Why?

Tags: django, include, block

This question is kinda similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3796462/1209416), except for one small change -

I have block tags in the parent.html, and some are filled in the calling template, some others in the included template. The included ones don't work. Eg:

```
#parent.html
<head>{% block head %}Parent head {% endblock %} </head>
<body> {% block body %} Parent body {% endblock %} 
</body>

#include.html

{%block body %} Child body {% endblock %}

#child.html
{% extends 'parent.html' %}

{% block head %}
Child head 
{% endblock %}

{% include 'include.html' %}
```

But this gives output :
Child head
Parent body

intsead of the desired :

Child head
Child body

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This :

```
{% include 'include.html' %}
```

is not included in any block, and will not be rendered, as you see in response.

Modify your child.html in that way:

```
#child.html
{% extends 'parent.html' %}

{% block head %}
Child head 
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% include 'include.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

if you want to define some html in both child.html and in include.html, then you should have:

```
#child.html
{% extends 'parent.html' %}

....

{% block body %}
    {% include 'include.html' %}
    some child html...
{% endblock %}
```

and in include.html:

```
{% block body %}
    {{ block.super }}
    some include html...
{% endblock %}
```

This will render:

```
some child html
some include html
```

Comment: I was thinking in the lines of having a footer.html that has a {% block footer %} Footer {%endblock %} that can be "plugged in" using an include tag in whichever template you are rendering - in a way, a maintanance-free (don't need to mention which block to go into every time) and multipurpose include. Guess it's not possible with Django.